# error encoding file with missing audio aac bitstream error

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, aac, bitstream

I have a video received from a client that when uploaded into our video processing server(Elemental Server) it hangs and never finishes. The error displayed is:

```
Can't decompress audio. Ignoring packet.
osl: [aac @ 0x7f90940031c0]Input buffer exhausted before END element found
```

Tried if it was possible to be fixed with ffmpeg using a simple copy format:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\broken.mp4" -c copy output.mp4"
```

,And this does not fix the problem with the audio stream, displaying error

```
aac bitstream error
```

every few lines.

I have tried to convert the video to mpeg but also fails obviously when reading the corrupted file:

```
Sample rate index in program config element does not match the sample rate index configured by the container.
```

Can the video file be fixed? The video plays ok in normal desktop however the audio has missing parts.
We wan't to keep the video as we cannot record it again while being able to encode to other required formats.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the video, you can try with -an (disable audio):

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\broken.mp4" -an -c copy output.mp4"
```